# CircleCI files are not synced to the server

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0

I'm new to the CircleCI and my config is as follows. I'm trying to rsync files to the server. The connection works fine, but after it's complete no files have been copied to server. Is there anything wrong with my paths and rsync command?

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: duanecilliers/alpine-composer-rsync:latest
    steps:
      - checkout
  deploy:
    machine:
      enabled: true
    steps:
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
          - "5e:3c:c3:58:9d:cf:fX:XX:XX:XX:XX:84:8a:b9:XX:XX"
      - run:
          name: Deploy Over SSH
          command: |
            rsync -e ssh -avvz --exclude=node_modules ~/project serverpilot@1XX.104.XX.XX:/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/XXXX/public/

workflows:
  version: 2
  build-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - build
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
```

I'm getting the following output.

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
rsync -e ssh -avvz --exclude=node_modules ./ serverpilot@172.XXX.XX.XX:/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/xxx/public/
opening connection using: ssh -l serverpilot 172.XXX.XX.XX rsync --server -vvlogDtprze.iLs . /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/xxx/public/  (9 args)
Warning: Permanently added '172.XXX.XX.XX' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

sending incremental file list
delta-transmission enabled
./
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0

sent 62 bytes  received 50 bytes  32.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no files being copied to your server because the `deploy` job doesn't have any files.

The `build` job gets files but the `checkout` step, which is basically a `git clone`. There's a few ways to get files into the `deploy` job but in this scenario, your best choice is to use [CircleCI Workspaces](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/concepts/#workspaces-and-artifacts) to copy files from the `build` job to the `deploy` job.